# Who invented the otpauth:// URI scheme?

Tags: uri, history

It seems really simple, but who invented the commonly-used `otpauth://` scheme (used by Google Authenticator and other TOTP soft tokens by scanning QR codes)? When?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about history, rather than an actual programming problem.


Comment: ["OTPauth is an open source, php-based, code library that is a two-factor authentication solution based on RFC 2289 - The One-Time Password."](https://code.google.com/p/otpauth/)

Comment: Look at [RFC2289](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2289.txt)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Fits with many of the other allowed questions correctly tagged with `history`. Which all feel like they are in a grey area. However, if not here than where?

Comment: @Matthew: TBH, I don't know the "correct" place to ask this (it may be worth asking at [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) where to ask this kind of thing).  But the SO remit is a lot tighter than it may have been in the past; questions should really be about tangible programming problems...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Then someone should look at deprecating the history tag...

Comment: @Matthew: I think that tag is often used for things like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634073/history-api-statechange-function-script-duplicates-function-calls-each-time-chan.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It is - but it specifically asks not to be, description: `DO NOT USE for questions that happen to contain the word "history". Use this tag for questions about the history of a programming concept or feature. such as: `http://stackoverflow.com/tags/history/info

Comment: @MikeW: RFC2289 does not mention the `otpauth://` URI scheme.

Comment: @MattBall: OTPauth is a PHP library, not the URI scheme I asked about.

Comment: I migrated this question to programmers.se http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/210597/who-invented-the-otpauth-uri-scheme